# How to change the CSS style of first-letter when hover over a parent element?

Tags: css

This is likely something I am just stupidly overlooking, but would you please tell me why hovering over the second division element doesn't cause the background color of the first letter to change to rgb(50,50,50) from rgb(150,150,150)?

Hovering over the first division, which starts out with no styling on the first letter, reacts to the style changes upon hover. But the second division, which starts out with the same styles that the first displays upon hover, does not change to the darker background upon hover.

I'm using the latest version of Firefox developer edition. I see now that it works in Chrome; so must be a Firefox issue.

Thank you.

```css
div > p:before { content: 'This text.'; }

div:nth-child(2) > p::first-letter,
div:first-child:hover > p::first-letter
{
 float: left;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
}

div:nth-child(2):hover > p::first-letter
{
 background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
}
```

```html
<div><p></p></div>

<div><p></p></div>
```

This snippet works in Firefox. It seems that to get the `::first-letter` to be styled both without and with `:hover` a letter has to be there apart from the content added by `:before` or `:after`.

```css
div > p:after { content: 'his text.' }

div > p::first-letter
 {
   float: left;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
  }
  
div:hover > p::first-letter
 {
  background-color: rgb(70,70,70);
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div><p>T</p></div>
```

I applied @Sydney Y's solution to the above snippet just to show that it works in Firefox. I don't think it is an isue of the `:hover` not being recognized because the snippet above recognizes it. It appears to be an issue of not including the text added through `:before { content: ... }` such that there is a first letter to which to apply the style.  But adding no content on `:hover` using `:after` seems to alter that and works for variable content.

I realize that this of little interest to anyone who doesn't want to use drop caps and change their style based on hover.

```css
div > p:before { content: 'This text.' }

div > p::first-letter
 {
   float: left;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
  }
  
div:hover > p::first-letter
 {
  background-color: rgb(70,70,70);
  color: white;
 }
 
 div:hover > p:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
<div><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, just some mix-ups, your accessors are correct.  Each block of CSS needs to apply to both divs:

```
  div > p:before { content: 'This text.'; }

div> p::first-letter {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: red;
 }

div:hover> p::first-letter{
 background: black;
}

div:hover > p:after { content: ''; }
```

Thanks for the snippet, that's cool!

Edit: getting closer!  Code is updated.  Still attempting on Firefox.

> Edit: Solved, kind of.  It works, but it's kind of a hack.   The
>   issue: In Firefox the hover doesn't trigger a repaint in this specific
>   instance, so I added an empty bit of content on hover because the
>   :after or content seem to have a kind of a hook.  You may be able to
>   achieve the same thing with a different hack other than content.

But good news is: this works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Awesome problem.  I can't imagine ever coming across this issue again, but it was super interesting to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Firefox at least, which is what I'm working in. I was aiming for what your code should do and added the first division just to show that hover is being recognized. But in the second div in my code, in Firefox, it does not change color. The first div will add the gray to the first letter on hover, but the second which starts out gray won't turn darker upon hover. Perhaps it is just a firefox issue.

Comment: @Gary I got it to work! (I messed with it a ton, so you may need to check I didn't break anything crucial to your specific setup)

Comment: Thanks for working it out further. For my particular case, the content isn't going to change; so, making the first letter fixed as in my second snippet will work. However, your solution is better, of course, since it will work for variable text and I think I will use it anyway.

Comment: I don't think that the `:hover` is not triggerring a repaint, as you put it, because in the second snippet it does repaint the first letter which is fixed and not added by `:after`. The browser just seems to not know what the first letter is when all of the text is added through the `content` style of `:before`, that is, until a `:hover` also adds nothing via `:after'.  Your code won't work in Firefox for any other style; so, I assume the issue must concern how the first letter is identified, such as looking at the HTML excluding content added in CSS.

Comment: Hm, in my Firefox (for Linux) neither div was changing on hover until I added the empty content to :after. I was also testing with only those 2 div>p's in the body. That's all from me; I'm satisfied with my answer

Comment: I intended to accept your answer when I last commented a few hours ago but clicked the up arrow instead of the check mark.  I clicked the check mark now. I didn't realize until reading your last comment and wondering what you meant by being satisfied with your answer. I wasn't criticizing your approach but simply pointing out that hover works in this case, for you can see it in the snippets. The second snippet demonstrates that, really the first does also; but Firefox doesn't recognize the first letter when all text is added in CSS only without your added hover after. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, no worries!  I just wanted to point out that my investigation was over.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in firefox that nth-child() is not going to work on  syntax that's why it is not working. Anyway if not want the same functionality as first one with different color this can be done with you just need to put hover in front of this code 
"div:nth-child(2) > p::first-letter,div:first-child:hover > p::first-letter ". I hope this will help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thank you for the information on the bug. If you mean `div:hover:nth-child(2)` and `div:hover:first-child`, it makes no difference here. At least I cannot get it to make a difference. It still doesn't work in Firefox. It behaves just as the first snippet does now.

Comment: "div:nth-child(2):hover  > p::first-letter,div:first-child:hover > p::first-letter" this is how you have to write.